# Cannot ping a certain IP address from machine within certain IP range?

Tags: networking, pfsense

I am a bit new to networking so I have probably done something wrong that is a simple oversight. I used to use an normal TP-Link router/switch combo jobs and an internal network range of 10.0.0.0/22. I had a couple of assigned IP's, the rest was through DHCP and everything was fine.

Then I switched to pfSense a couple of days ago using the same network range. I set up the DHCP range from 10.0.3.0 to 10.0.3.254 because I wanted to be able to statically assign IP's in the range 10.0.0.0-10.0.2.255.

I have a QNAP NAS setup which I have always assigned the IP 10.0.1.2, even on the old TP-Link router. But now, for some reason, I cannot ping or connect to that IP unless the source IP is 10.0.1.x

For example:

**Laptop - 10.0.3.87**

- Ping 10.0.1.1 - SUCCESS
- Ping 10.0.1.2 - DESTINATION HOST UNREACHABLE
- Ping 10.0.1.3 - SUCCESS

**Desktop - 10.0.1.10**

- Ping 10.0.1.1 - SUCCESS
- Ping 10.0.1.2 - SUCCESS
- Ping 10.0.1.3 - SUCCESS

I am very confused as to what is going on here, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you set the Netmask on your QNAP to /22 (255.255.252.0)?

Comment: Yup. The subnet mask is /22 on all devices.

Comment: Can you ping the Desktop from your Laptop?

Comment: Yeah, it is literally just 10.0.1.2 I cannot connect to unless the source IP is 10.0.1.X

Comment: Could you set the QNAP to DHCP for testing and ping it from both hosts?

Comment: So I ended up discovering what the problem was. For some reason, the NAS had created a route to an empty LXC container that happened to be the on the same subnet. The traffic was being routed to this LXC container and not making it back to the source. Deleting the route managed to fix everything. Although I don't know why this has just become an issue because the route to the LXC container was there when using the old TP-Link router.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up discovering what the problem was. For some reason, the NAS had created a route to an empty LXC container that happened to be the on the same subnet. The traffic was being routed to this LXC container and not making it back to the source. Deleting the route managed to fix everything. Although I don't know why this has just become an issue because the route to the LXC container was there when using the old TP-Link router.